# Increasing ListBox populating performance

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

My WPF listbox has virtualization on and binds to ObservableCollection. I get increased performance on adding items if I remove ItemsSource before adding all items to collection and then rebind it afterwards, but it stills hangs for 3 seconds on 1000+ items

```
this.listbox.ItemsSource = null;
//add a bunch of files to ObservableCollection
this.listbox.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyCollectionView);
```

Also it seems there is small increase in performance if I use CollectionViewSource as ItemsSource instead of collection directly.

ItemTemplate is not very complicated - has 5 TextBlocks in DockPanel binded to ViewModel with IsAsync=False (because slowly appearing data on scroll looks bad here).

Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi Milo, the hang happens only one time in your app or you often add 1000+ items??

Comment: Sounds more like a data problem than a ListBox problem to me.  Are you sure the delay is occurring when you're adding the items to the ListBox, and not when you're retrieving the items from... wherever you're getting them from?  Might be worth your time to throw a stopwatch in and figure out where the biggest delay is occurring.

Comment: I would bind to a public property and I would add the 1000+ items in a a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @dotsamuelswan You were partially right as one second went on updating DependencyProperty on each iteration. The rest two seconds go on creating ListBoxItems according to DataTemplate. Is there a way to speed those up? What is faster and requires least measuring: Grid/DockPanel/StackPanel?

Comment: It's tough to say what the best path is without seeing more of your code.  It's likely that you can be more efficient with how you're mapping your data into the collection you are binding to.